# Fake bot orders Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I've installed Wordpress with Azera Shop theme. For development time, whole page is protected with .htpasswd, but - after about a week there was few orders from bots.

It could be easy thing if we have buying functionality (captcha), BUT - all prices are Null, so in that theme - all elements like "Add to cart" etc. are 
just disabled.

Orders are without any products set, with random price, date and status.

[image: SAMPLE OF THE ORDERS]

What could be the problem? First thing that make me curious is overpassing through .htpasswd, next - how the orders are set? I guess that there wasn't a SQL injection used, but, maybe some of you have ever seen similar problem.

From that moment, I've installed anti-spam plugin from webvitaly and set all products status to "unavailable" and it's propably working.

Thanks

Comment: the list of possibilities approach infinity,

Answer (score 0):

There could be  Nth number of reason.

Could you please make true the Debug and Error, so that you could troubleshoot the issue from the Code view and see the Deprecated Code and Runtime Error as well. Also make sure you have Firewall is active. 
This could be the basic things that bot bypass.